# Not to send SIGINT to a child when SIGINT is sent to a parent

Tags: c, linux, signals, sigint, execve

Is there a way to not sent `SIGINT` to a child process when `SIGINT` is sent to a parent? Example:

`main.c`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>

int run_python(void* arg){
    (void) arg;
    char *const args[] = {"python3", "run.py", NULL };
    execve("/usr/bin/python3", args, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int main(void){
    char *stack = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, 1234, 0);
    clone(run_python, stack + 4096,  0, NULL);
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

The program that is being run as a child `run.py`:

```
import sys
import time
import signal

f = open("output.output", 'w')

def recieved_sigint(*args):
    print("Received sigint", file=f, flush=True)
    sys.exit(1)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, recieved_sigint)

while(True):
    print("Test", file=f, flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is when executing `main.c` and pressing `Ctrl+C` the `run.py` program also receives `SIGINT`. The string `"Received sigint"` is printed.

Is there a way to not send `SIGINT` to a child that was `clone`ed-`execve`ed?

Comment: Do `signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);` before `clone(...);` (and `signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);` directly after `clone(...);` if you want the parent to receive them). Or `clone()` with `CLONE_SIGHAND` or `CLONE_CLEAR_SIGHAND` and let the python script do `SIG_IGN`.

Comment: You can also create new session with `setsid()` before `execve()`. But child process will be out of shell's job control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this is the kernel sending keyboard-generated signals, such as `SIGINT`, to all processes in the [process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) attached to the terminal.

Block `SIGINT` in the parent with [`sigprocmask`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) before spawning children with `clone`. The children inherit the signal mask.

After spawning children unblock `SIGINT`. A pending `SIGINT` will be delivered upon unblocking, if any.

Ignoring the signal with `SIG_IGN` while spawning children processes risks discarding the signal which may lead to sporadic missed signal race conditions which don't reproduce reliably.